# Java built-in class to interface

Tags: java, class, interface, built-in

Can you create an interface that inherits all functions of an java built-in class?

What I am trying to do:

I have a lot of classes that extends Fragment, in the classes there are some attributes (get, set) and some functions. After making objects of the different classes I put them in one general Fragment list.

But I want to introduce polymorphism: 1 interface class and all the other classes implement that so they can override the functions.

But the problem is that if I want to use polymorphism I need an interface, and the interface should be an Fragment so I still can put these fragments in to a list, so could I create an interface from the Fragment class or can the interface inherit from the fragments?

On the image you could see the current situation

[image: current]

### Update

Here is some code to show what I want to achieve:

So I have my main function which is an xmlSAXParser, when I encounter a tag I create an object of the correct class:

```
case template:
        switch (typeObjecten.toType(atType)) {
        case NOVALUE:
            break;
        case chapter:
            chapter = new ChapterFragment();
            typeObject = "chapter";
            break;
        case execute:
            execute = new ExecuteFragment();
            typeObject = "execute";
            break;
        case first:
            first = new FirstFragment();
            typeObject = "first";
            break; 
                              ...
```

When I found the end tag I add the right object to the list:

```
case template:
        switch (typeObjecten.toType(typeObject)) {
        
        case NOVALUE:
            break;
        case chapter:
            fragments.add(ownFrag);
            break;
        case execute:
            fragments.add(execute);
            break;
        case first:
            fragments.add(first);
            break;
        case navigation:
            fragments.add(navigation);
            break;
        case story:
            fragments.add(story);
            break;
                          ....
```

It is also possible that in every class the background could change, now I have to check which class the object is to call the correct function:

```
case background:
        
        if (typeObject.equalsIgnoreCase("navigation")) {
            navigation.setBackgroundColor("#" + text);
        } else if (typeObject.equalsIgnoreCase("chapter")) {
            //chapter.setBackgroundColor("#" + text);
        } else if (typeObject.equalsIgnoreCase("first")) {
            ownFrag.setBackgroundColor("#" + text);
            first.setBackgroundColor("#" + text);
        } else if (typeObject.equalsIgnoreCase("execute")) {
            execute.setBackgroundColor("#" + text);
        } else if (typeObject.equalsIgnoreCase("story")) {
            story.setBackgroundColor("#" + text);
        } else if (typeObject.equalsIgnoreCase("intro")) {
            intro.setBackgroundColor("#" + text);
        } else if (typeObject.equalsIgnoreCase("mission")) {
            mission.setBackgroundColor("#" + text);
        } else if (typeObject.equalsIgnoreCase("question")) {
            question.setBackgroundColor("#" + text);
        } else if (typeObject.equalsIgnoreCase("info")) {
            info.setBackgroundColor("#" + text);
        }
        break;
                   ...
```

So it would be nice if I could make an 'global' Fragment and then that the program finds out itself which function from which class it has to call (polymorphism?)

Comment: `interface SubFragment extends Fragment {...}` ?

Comment: When you say 'I want to introduce polymorphism', what specifically do you want it for?

Comment: @assylias I get an error on that: Fragment cannot be resolved to a type

Comment: @Zutty Because I parse an xml and depending on the tag I create an object of the correct class and then i set the properties. 

Now it are 15 different classes wich says that for each tag i have to check 15 times wich function it has to call, with polymorphism I could let the program decide wich function

Comment: @GuntherVanGeetsom is Fragment an interface?

Comment: @assylias it is called Fragment.class in the folder so I suppose it is a class yeah

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another option is to make Fragment abstract and have your classes extend it. Then you could also add in some shared functionality if possible.

Based on you comment that Fragment is a built in class and not editable it seems there are a couple of options. You could reference Objects extending Fragment generically <? extends Fragment> or by creating a wrapper class over Fragment that holds and maintains an instance of it. This would give you more control.

A simple example could be something like the following.

```
class CannotModify{
    public void doSomething(){}
}




public interface AddThisIfYouWant{
    public void doSomething();
}




public class Wrap extends CannotModify, implements AddThisIfYouWant{
    private final CannotModify yourInstance;

    public Wrap(){
        this.yourInstance=new CannotModify();
    }

    @Override
    public void doSomething(){
        super.doSomething();
    }

}
```

You could also just extend Fragment if you only need to reference your Objects at the Fragment level. For example:

```
public class AnotherFragment extends Fragment{...}

...
public void somethingWithFragments(List<? extends Fragment> fragments){
    for(Fragment fragment:fragments){
        ...
    }
}
...
```

Comment: That seems the problem, the Fragment is an built-in class so I can't change a thing

Comment: Sorry, I didnt know that. Ill append my answer.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but could you maybe explain a little bit more, maybe with an example?

Comment: Yeah sure. I just added an example.

Comment: okey nice thank you, so if I would use polymorphism I have to add all the common function into the interface?


Then in my main program i have to create an new Wrap like 

`Wrap myWrap = new ChapterFragment();`   //my defined class

then I could set `myWrap.setBackground(color);`

and then add the wrap to an list of Fragments?

Comment: Hmm it seems it doesn't work, when i launch my app I get one blank screen, it seems that the function of the class chapter is not called

Comment: I updated my answer to show an alternative approach. Im not sure what your code is doing internally can you edit your question, to show the relevant code?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/26052/discussion-between-gunther-van-geetsom-and-john-kane)

Comment: I cant do that right now, Im not sure I fully understand what you are trying to do though. Are you just trying to set default attributes for a given type? you could most likely do that in a constructor.

Comment: Like you could see in my class diagram, there are different classes (wich represent a template, with their own layouts). 

I have an xml where are different tags for each template like backgroundcolor, text color, text itself. So when i parse a tag I have to set the right properties to the right class. 

What i want to try is that I don't have to check wich object is currently created, so I could call   globalFragment.setBackground(color) and that the program then sees that the object is of the type ChapterFragment so it calls the function setBackground from the ChapterFragmentClass

Comment: When you create the Object you can set its properties. If you need to update groups of objects based on their type, it might make sense to keep a collection of them in some form allowing you to do this. Another option would be to take a look at the adapter pattern or something like that. However, if you just want to be able to change values of everything globally, maybe try to give each fragment a reference to the same object or something like that.

Comment: Could you maybe give an example based on my code? I'm sorry but I find it difficult to understand without some code

Comment: Im not sure what you are trying to do, or what part you are having difficulty with. Im assuming you are parsing through xml, generating classes and setting attributes on each class based on the values parsed out?

Comment: yes correct that is what I have already achieved but I wanted to 'compress' my code because every class has the tag background and so the function background, and a lot of classes has te function setText etc.. Like you could see in the code in my question i have to check with a lot if else if wich class function i have to call (ex: if (object == navigation) navigation.setBackground  else if (object == chapter) chaper.setBackground).. With polymorphism I could replace that with generalObject.setBackground and then it would call the correct setBackground itself

Comment: Add whatever functionality is or can be shared to the base class, otherwise do the specific implementations in your child classes. It seems fairly strait forward?

Comment: haha yes, but now we are at the beginning of the problem, the base class is the Fragment class where I can't the shared functionality

Comment: In my answer I showed you a way around this by creating a wrapper class. You can default whatever values are needed in the constructor, or add a separate method call/way to populate them.

Answer (score 1):

**Edited after the information that Fragment is a build-in class.**

The answer to your underlying question is: NO, in Java you cannot extend a predefined class with new behavior (such as, to make it implement another interface). You can do that in Objective-C, for example. But it does not look like you need that in your case.

Define a subclass of Fragment that has the behavior that you need, and implements the interfaces that you need it to implement, and derive your other classes from that subclass.

**Old answer:**

You give the answer yourself already:

> But the problem is that if I want to use polymorphism i need an
>   interface, and the interface should be an Fragment

As you have sketched the class diagram right now, the Fragment class has no data and no default behavior, and therefore there is no reason at all to make it a base class of all the other classes. Just define Fragment as an interface (with the method declarations that you need), and specify for the other classes that they implement that interface.

Comment: I'm sorry for the misunderstanding, the Fragment class is an built-in class so it has a lot of functions

Answer (score 0):

You should create an interface for the Fragment and make all the classes extend that interface

Answer (score 0):

first of all. No an interface cant extend a class, that would break the semantics of an interface (only signatures).

What u can do is let "Fragment" simply implement that newly created Interfaces.

Comment: interfaces can extend other interfaces (not sure what the person asking the question is really looking for)

Comment: Yep, only other interfaces but not classes as i mentioned :) I think fragment is an abstract or concrete class in this case.

Comment: I know, I was just adding that because I am not sure what they are looking for. There are cases where it makes sense to have a hierarchy  of interfaces, other times just using an abstract (or even just a base) class will work.

Comment: @ThomasErnst I can't edit the Fragment class because it is an built-in class

Comment: Then i would say create an own base class / adapter which extends / delegates to fragment and is implementing your interface. All your concrete classes should then inherit from that new class.

Answer (score 0):

You can make a general `FragmentInterface` and other Interfaces that extend that `FragmentInterface`.

Why do you need only 1 interface when you can make a base interface, and other interfaces that extend that base interface?

By the way, a class can also implement multiple `interfaces`.

Comment: but the FragmentInterface needs al functions of the built-in class 'Fragment', so I could use the functions of Fragment